# QGIS: How to exclude outliers from the legend classfication using an expression

Tags: qgis, classification, outlier

I am trying to make an equal interval legend using a rate of burglaries per 1000 habitants using a combination of a column with the counts of burglaries and a column of total population using census districts. Due to the fact that there are outliers in the data (extremely high values) I would like to exclude them from the process of defining classes in the legend based on a threshold of the total population (less than 700).  I already build a expression in the expression function (which exclude values <700) window like this:

CASE WHEN  "burglaries_CS_POPN_2000|2000"  >= 700 THEN ( "burglaries_P500_ALL|2009"  /   "burglaries_CS_POPN_2000|2000" )  END

It works fine, but the polygons excluded are not showed anymore.  In ArcGis there is an option for "show symbol for excluded data" in the symbology-classification window.
Is there an option in QGIS that could perform the same task without adding a new column in the attribute table? Could it be done using an expression like I show above?

Answer (score 1):

I actually will remove values above a certain threshold (1.5 Standard deviations above and below the average and rerun interpolation sometimes to show the more subtle differences in the data. I will make one layer that has the outliers still in it with a color scheme like shades of red. Then I will place a transparent outliers-removed version over it so that the super high readings show up below while still displaying the more subtle (though sometimes more important) clouds or clusters.

I would also like to see some better option!